# FullCalender.js onclick event not working after view changed

Tags: fullcalendar

I have added onclick event on the Fullcalender.js on the events. But when I am changing the calender view from Month to Week or Day that onclick event is not working anymore. Please help me how to fix this.

Here is my code for the first time after the page load, it working perfectly but after the change of view the click is not working:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Appointment/GetAgendaList",
        data: {userid:@Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"])},
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (response) {
            debugger;
            //load all events
            LoadEvents(response);
        }
    });

    //Add click events on each Event link to get details
    var clicks = 0;
    $('td.fc-event-container a').on({
        click: function (event) {
            node = $(this);
            clicks++;
            if (clicks == 1) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if (clicks == 1) {
                        $('#loderdiv').show();

                        var loadurl = $('input#hdneventdetailsurl').val();
                        var eventid = $(node).find('input.hdneve_id').val();
                        loadurl = loadurl + "/" + eventid;
                        $('#myagenda').load(loadurl, function () {
                            $('div#myagenda').modal('show');
                            $('#loderdiv').hide();
                        });
                    }
                    clicks = 0;
                }, 300);
            }
        }
    });
});

//Initialize the calender and add all events
function LoadEvents(data)
{
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events:data
    });
}
```

Comment: Why you use click++? any special reason? I have solution without click++.

Comment: Have you seen the documentation about the included [eventClick](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) option, instead of rolling  your own?